# Terminology for relationship between types formed by type classes

Tags: scala, terminology, typeclass

Object oriented programming uses terms like is-a (inheritance)

```
class Cat extends Animal
// cat is-a animal
```

and has-a (composition)

```
class Car(engine: Engine)
// car has-a engine
```

to describe relationships between types. Along those lines, what would be terminology used to describe the relation between two types created by a type class

```
List  ?  Functor[List]
    |___|
      |
what relation is this?
```

Comment: Not sure how formal this would be, but it is usually mentioned that `List` **HAS A** `Functor` instance associated with it; this is useful to distinguish it from subclassing polymorphisms and has the intuition of the compiler finding the instance associated with it. - More formally I believe the correct expression is **FORMS A** but for that expression to make sense, you need to have the context that a **Typeclass** instance is a triplet of 1) A type or kind - 2) The implementation of the abstract methods for the current type / kind - 3) A proof of the satisfaction of the laws.

Comment: I would just say Functor applies to List.

Comment: I'd second Luis's comment. Dima: I'd say vice versa that List belongs to Functor :)

Comment: "for-a" might also be appropriate, as in "functor for a list".

Comment: @DmytroMitin then in the case of `Car(engine: Engine)` you would also want to say "Engine belongs to Car" :) But that doesn't make any sense: engine doesn't know anything about cars that use it. The car knows which engine it uses, a functor knows which type it applies to, not the other way around.

Comment: @Dima I'm not arguing but one of the ways to look at type classes is that a type class is a set of types for which there are defined instances of the type class. So I meant "belongs" in set-theoretic sense.

Comment: So both kinds and type classes can be seen as sets of types, just in different ways.

Comment: @Dima Well, if you define an instance in the companion object or `Functor` then `Functor` knows about `List`, if you do in the comanion object of `List` then `List` knows about `Functor` :)